# Java issues with all my color changing and the drawing not starting when I click

Tags: java, swing

I am having an issue figuring out why my code isn't working for when I click to turn the drawing on/off. It should start as off initially but it doesn't. I also have an issue with my arraylist where I am not sure how to make it so that all the colors don't change when I click on a new color. This is my code so far, any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

public class Draw extends JPanel {

private Point startPoint, endPoint;
private ArrayList<Point> pointList;
private JButton clear;
private JRadioButton red, yellow, blue, eraser;
private boolean clicked;
private final static int SIZE = 30;

public Draw() {
    // set the background color
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    // set starting point and end point of mouse click
    startPoint = null;
    endPoint = null;

    this.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
    this.addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseListener());

    clicked = false;
    pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();

    this.addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseListener());

    clear = new JButton("Clear Drawing");
    this.add(clear);
    clear.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    red = new JRadioButton("Red", true);
    this.add(red);
    red.addActionListener(new OptionListener());

    yellow = new JRadioButton("Yellow", false);
    this.add(yellow);
    yellow.addActionListener(new OptionListener());

    blue = new JRadioButton("Blue", false);
    this.add(blue);
    blue.addActionListener(new OptionListener());

    eraser = new JRadioButton("Eraser",false);
    this.add(eraser);
    eraser.addActionListener(new OptionListener());

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(red);
    group.add(yellow);
    group.add(blue);
    group.add(eraser);
}

private class OptionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        repaint();
    }
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == clear) {
            pointList.clear();
            repaint();
        } else {
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        if (clicked) {
            pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();
            pointList.add(event.getPoint());
            endPoint = null;
        } else {
            endPoint = event.getPoint();
            startPoint = null;
        }
        clicked = !clicked;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        pointList.add(event.getPoint());
        repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics pen) {
    super.paintComponent(pen);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pen;
    for (Point p : pointList) {
        if (red.isSelected()) {
            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(p.getX(), p.getY(), SIZE, SIZE));
        } else if (yellow.isSelected()) {
            g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(p.getX(), p.getY(), SIZE, SIZE));
        } else if (blue.isSelected()) {
            g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(p.getX(), p.getY(), SIZE, SIZE));
        } else {

        }
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing Time");
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            // create an object of your class
            Draw panel = new Draw();
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Understand that it is hard to debug someone else's unexplained code, and also understand that your job is to help us understand, to help us help you.

Comment: 1) `private boolean clicked;` If there is any valid reason for keeping this field, it should be a `JCheckBox`. A glance at the code suggests it is redundant, but I've not looked closely enough at it to be certain. 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 3) *"I also have an issue with.."* ..understanding this is a Q&A Site, not a help desk? Each thread should contain one clear, specific question rather than two or more 'issues'.

Answer (score 1):

> I also have an issue with my arraylist where I am not sure how to make it so that all the colors dont change when I click on a new color

There are two ways to do custom painting:

1. paint to a BufferedImage. Using this approach the object is painted and the currently selected color will be used to paint the object
2. (the approach you are using) - store the object you want to paint in an ArrayList. The problem is you are only storing the Point objects in the list so all Points get repainted with the same color. If you want each Point to have a different Color, then you need to store a custom Object that contains both the Color and the Point.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of both of these approaches.

You need to associate the Color with each individual object that you paint.